# Github error in VSC

Tags: git, github

I'm still a newbie in Github and when i'm trying to pull and push, i always get this error,

```
> git pull --tags
> git show :_gitdar/app/core/Route.php
> git show :_gitdar/index.php
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
> git show :_gitdar/app/core/Route.php
> git show :_gitdar/index.php
> git fetch
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git show :_gitdar/app/core/Route.php
> git show :_gitdar/index.php
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
```

where i should fix this? visual studio code always give me this output every time i pull and push on git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, switch back to command line, and do a `git status` in your local repo.

Second, if Git (through Visual Studio Code) doesn't even know master, it is possible that you have not yet added and committed files, before attempting to push.
That or you are in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

Comment: I actually tried to push a one file which is the .htaccess but then the second push it gives me that error already.

Comment: @kimnicole again, a git status should at least give more information.